# how to detect a pin change of a GPIO on Linux board

Tags: c, linux, posix, embedded-linux, gpio

I am using 3.12 kernel on an ARM based linux board (imx233 CPU). My purpose is to detect pin change of a GPIO (1 to 0).

I can read the pin value constantly calling the below function (in a while(1) loop)

```
int GPIO_read_value(int pin){
    int gpio_value = 0;
    char path[35] = {'\0'};
    FILE *fp;
    sprintf(path, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", pin);
    if ((fp = fopen(path,"rb+")) == NULL){ //echo in > direction
         //error
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &gpio_value);
    fclose(fp);
    return gpio_value;
}
```

But it causes too much load to the CPU. I don't use `usleep` or `nanosleep`, because the pin change happens for a very short of a time that would cause me to miss the event.

As far as I find out, it is not possible to use `poll()`. Is there any `poll()` like function that I can use to detect a pin change of a GPIO?

EDIT: Just in case, if I am doing something wrong,  here is my `poll()` usage that does not detect the pin change

```
struct pollfd pollfds;
    int fd;
    int nread, result;
    pollfds.fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio51/value", O_RDWR);
    int timeout = 20000;           /* Timeout in msec. */
    char buffer[128];

    if( pollfds.fd < 0 ){
        printf(" failed to open gpio \n");
        exit (1);
    }

    pollfds.events = POLLIN;
    printf("fd opens..\n");
    while (1)
    {
            result = poll (&pollfds, 0, timeout);
            switch (result)
            {
                  case 0:
                    printf ("timeout\n");
                    break;
                  case -1:
                    printf ("poll error \n");
                    exit (1);

                   default:
                printf("something is happening..\n");
                    if (pollfds.revents & POLLIN)
                    {
                        nread = read (pollfds.fd, buffer, 8);
                        if (nread == 0) {
                            printf ("result:%d\n", nread);
                            exit (0);
                         } else {
                            buffer[nread] = 0;
                            printf ("read %d from gpio: %s", nread, buffer);
                         }
                     }
              }
     }
     close(fd);
```

EDIT2: the code on https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Gpio-int-test.c works fine with `poll()` I needed to define the rising/falling edge for the interrupt and a little bit fix on the definition. It solves my problem, however, it might be good for me and some other people to hear/know the alternative methods.

Comment: what about the inotify API?

Comment: When you say that the pin is only active for a "very short time", what kind of timing are you talking about? Because having even active polling like you do, doing it from userspace might introduce latencies that can cause you to miss it anyway.

Comment: I want to use a GPIO as a chipselect to read SPI data. on the idle state it is logic high. It goes to logic low when the transmission starts. Therefore, the faster reaction the better. When I find an appropriate method, I will test it with slower speed

Comment: Does this particular pin have an alternative capture-compare function? What you need is the hardware to generate an interrupt

Comment: Right, HW interrupt would be the best. But, I could not find the support for my board (olimex imx233nano) yet. It would be good to know a Linux/posix function that would work fine. As true suggests, I am trying inotify now.

Comment: You could abstract the input as a GPIO key: http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=GPIO_keys.  You can be notified of rise and fall with timestamps.  Pinctrl may also allow application of HW  debounce or deglitch.

Comment: @angs, considering that this is based on imx CPU, were you able to check what kind of irqs are registered and importantly gpio_to_irq() ?

Comment: @angs take a look at [libsoc](https://github.com/jackmitch/libsoc). It provides a routine to wait for a GPIO interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this board before, however I guess PIC is fully implemented for this board (usually is like that) but you have to configure interrupt additionally in GPIO controller (usually is like that).
Some part should be done as a kernel module, then you have to pass information about interrupt to you application.

Example way to do this is to implement following thing as a kernel module:

- setup GPIO controller to enable interrupt on particular port and level
  (how to do this you can find here: http://cache.freescale.com/files/dsp/doc/ref_manual/IMX23RM.pdf 37.2.3.3 Input Interrupt Operation)
- enable GPIO interrupt in PIC (how to do this: http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch10.pdf Chapter10)
- implement interrupt handling routine (I will describe a little bit below)
- implement ioctl interfaces for your module.

and a rest in your application:

- a function that can coosomeoneperate with interrupt.

Simplest way of passing information about interrupt from kernel to app is by semaphore on kernel side.
in module you can implement an ioctl that will sleep until interrupt happen. 
So application will call this ioctl and its thread will be blocked until interrupt happen.

Inside module, interrupt routine should check if application thread is now blocked, and if so up() semaphore.

EDIT*****

This CPU has SSP that has working mode for SPI. Why dont use it ??